# How to remove or change port number once allocated

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2003

1. I have .exe file which only run the application(not a setup) of 1 mb...if i run it on windowes 2003 server it normally ask for port number...i hvae allocated a port ,now it is giving an arreor (;6overflow)...application is buit in vb6.
2. to solve this problem i want o give a try by changing port no...how can i remove/change port no once allocated???

Comment: can some can correct spelling mistake like 'windowes', 'hvae', 'arreor'.

Plus I don't really understand the meaning of port ? what port TCP/IP, PIPE, socket ....

Answer (score 0):

All you can do is tell the app to use a different port number at startup but as soon as the OS has allocated a port for you, you can't change it's number.

The only workaround is using something like netcat which can forward all traffic from one port to another. So while your app is still running on port X, netcat can connect that port to Y, so for anyone outside, it will look as if your app is serving from both X and Y.